# ASP.NET 3.5 precompilation [NullReferenceException]

Tags: asp.net, pre-compilation

I'm getting a null reference for an asp.net application while running precompile using aspnet_compiler. There's no specific error however i have this in the build log.

```
[NullReferenceException]: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CopyPrecompiledFile(VirtualFile vfile, String destPhysicalPath)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CopyStaticFilesRecursive(VirtualDirectory sourceVdir, String destPhysicalDir, Boolean topLevel)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CopyStaticFilesRecursive(VirtualDirectory sourceVdir, String destPhysicalDir, Boolean topLevel)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.PrecompileAppInternal(VirtualPath startingVirtualDir)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.PrecompileApp(VirtualPath startingVirtualDir)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.PrecompileApp(ClientBuildManagerCallback callback)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManagerHost.PrecompileApp(ClientBuildManagerCallback callback)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManagerHost.PrecompileApp(ClientBuildManagerCallback callback)
   at System.Web.Compilation.ClientBuildManager.PrecompileApplication(ClientBuildManagerCallback callback, Boolean forceCleanBuild)
   at System.Web.Compilation.ClientBuildManager.PrecompileApplication(ClientBuildManagerCallback callback)
   at System.Web.Compilation.Precompiler.Main(String[] args)
```

Things i've tried so far,

- Clearing temp
- Assigning permissions to folders
- Checked for folder compression
- Checked for *.compiled files in bin
- Deleted *.ddl refresh dlls in bin

I'm running build from command line with the following,

```
c:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\MSBuild.exe Build.xml /target:Precompile  > log\Precompile.txt
```

This is the target definition in the build xml

```
  <Target Name="Precompile"> 
      <Exec
        Command="&quot;C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_compiler&quot; -v Web -p E:\Src\Web -u -f -d -fixednames E:\Output -errorstack" 
        WorkingDirectory="."
        ContinueOnError="false"/>   
</Target>
```

So far nothing has helped, i've taken this up from a colleague who says it was working fine the other day, **how do i go about troubleshooting this?** Build is running and the exit happens only towards the end, another thing is its running ok from visual studio, only the command line build is breaking, any pointers ? thanks